# Does a discrete (and closed) set have an accumulation point?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(E,\tau)$ be a topological space, $\mathcal N_\tau(x):=\{N\subseteq E:N\text{ is a }\tau\text{-neighborhood of }B\}$ for $x\in E$ and $B\subseteq E$. Remember that $x\in E$ is called

- $\tau$-accumulation point of $B$ if $$\forall N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x):B\cap N\setminus\{x\}\ne\emptyset;\tag1$$
- $\tau$-isolated point of $B$ if $$\exists N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x):B\cap N=\{x\}\tag2.$$

Moreover, $B$ is called $\tau$-discrete if every point in $B$ is an $\tau$-isolated point of $B$; i.e. $$\forall x\in B:\exists N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x):B\cap N=\{x\}\tag3.$$

> Assume $B$ is $\tau$-discrete. Can we show that $B$ has no $\tau$-accumulation point or do we need to additionally assume that $B$ is $\tau$-closed (i.e. $E\setminus B\in\tau$)?

Let $x\in E$. If $x\in B$, then $$B\cap N=\{x\}\tag4$$ and hence $$B\cap N\setminus\{x\}=\emptyset\tag5$$ for some $N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x)$; hence $x$ is not a $\tau$-accumulation point of $B$.

Now assume $x\in E\setminus B$. If $B$ would be $\tau$-closed, we would clearly find a $N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x)$ with $N\subseteq E\setminus B$ and hence $(5)$ would hold again and we we could conclude that $x$ is not a $\tau$-accumulation point of $B$.

> But do we really need the $\tau$-closedness assumption? If so, can it be shown that the following equivalence holds: $B$ is $\tau$-closed and $\tau$-discrete if and only if $B$ has no $\tau$-accumulation point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $B$ being $\tau$-discrete does *not* imply it has no accumulation points, as the standard example $B=\{\frac1n\mid n \in \Bbb N^+\}$ in $\Bbb R$ in the standard topology shows. Here $0 \in B'$.

If $B$ is closed and $\tau$-discrete then it indeed does not have an accumulation point: if $p$ were one, it must lie in $B$ by closedness and this would contradict the discreteness of $B$.

And the condition is necessary of course: a set $B$ has no acculation points iff it is closed and $\tau$-discrete. We just saw the left to right implication, and *if* a set has no accumulation points, it is closed (voidly, as a set is closed iff it contains all its accumulation points, which is trvial when there are none) and $\tau$-discrete (as no $b \in B$ is an accumulation point it must be an isolated point (it's one or the other).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your example, if $\tau$ is the Euclidean topology on $(0,1]$, $B$ is $\tau$-discrete and has no $\tau$-accumulation point, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, on $(0,1]$ my $B$ is closed and $\tau$-discrete. We cannot see the missing $0$.

Answer (score 1):

> Counterexample For Your First Question:

Take $E := \mathbb R$ with the standard topology. $B := \{1/n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ is a discrete set w.r.t. the standard topology but clearly $0$ is an accumulation point of $B$. So discreteness by itself is not sufficient to guarantee no accumulation point.